# What is the defined behavior of SQLite when interleaving statements that affect each other?

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite if I prepare a `SELECT` statement and begin stepping through it, then before the last row of the results is reached I execute another statement that has an effect on the `SELECT` statement that I am stepping through, what is the expected result?

I can't find anything in the SQLite documentation about what is supposed to happen but it seems like an extremely common case when programming in a multi-threaded environment.

Below is a c++ file that can be compiled and run on Windows to demonstrate the situation.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Knownfolders.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <comdef.h>

using namespace std;

int exec_sql(sqlite3 *db, const char* sql)
{
    char *errmsg;
    int result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << errmsg << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << "Running jsqltst with SQLite version: ";
    cout << sqlite3_libversion();
    cout << endl;

    PWSTR userhome;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Profile, NULL, NULL, &userhome))) {
        cout << "Failed getting user home dir\n";
        return -1;
    }

    wcout << "User home: " << userhome << endl;

    wchar_t *ws1 = userhome, *ws2 = L"\\test.sqlite";
    wstring dbpath_str(ws1);
    dbpath_str += wstring(ws2);
    _bstr_t dbpath(dbpath_str.c_str());

    cout << "DB path: " << dbpath << endl;

    sqlite3 *db;

    int result = sqlite3_open_v2(dbpath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    const char * create_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS atable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, number INTEGER);";
    if (exec_sql(db, create_stmt) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    const char * delete_stmt = "DELETE FROM atable;";
    if (exec_sql(db, delete_stmt) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    const char * insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO atable (name,number) VALUES ('Beta',77),('Alpha',99);";
    if (exec_sql(db, insert_stmt) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    sqlite3_stmt* select_ss;
    const char * select_stmt = "SELECT * FROM atable;";
    result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, select_stmt, -1, &select_ss, NULL);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    boolean gotrow;
    do {
        result = sqlite3_step(select_ss);
        gotrow = result == SQLITE_ROW;
        if (gotrow) {
            i++;
            cout << "I got a row!" << endl;

            if (i == 1) {
                if (exec_sql(db, insert_stmt) != 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    } while (gotrow);

    cout << "Last result: " << result << ", errstr: " << sqlite3_errstr(result) << endl;

    result = sqlite3_finalize(select_ss);
    if (result != SQLITE_OK) {
        cout << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible answers: http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've looked at both those before. The first simply explains how SQLite ensures the DB is never corrupted and handles errors when committing changes, and the second simply says "yup it is threadsafe" but doesn't explain the expected behavior.

Comment: This page seems a little bit more helpful, and it contains some interesting point at the end about temporary tables, I will need to read more about those and see if they provide a solution to this problem: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=MultiThreading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite's behaviour for concurrent statements in the same transaction is neither documented nor defined.

As you have seen, newly inserted records might be seen when a `SELECT`'s cursor has not yet reached that part of the table.
However, if SQLite needed to create a temporary result table for sorting or grouping, later changes in the table will not appear in that result.
Whether you have a temporary table or not might depend on decisions made by the query optimizer, so this is often not predictable.

If multiple threads access the same connection, SQLite will lock the DB around each `sqlite3_step` call.
This prevent data corruption, but you will still have the problem that automatic transaction end when their last active statement ends, and that explicit transaction will fail the `COMMIT` if there is some other active statement.

Multi-threaded programs are better off using (at least) one connection per thread.

Comment: Good answer, it would be nice if the authors acknowledged this in the documentation somewhere. It would be even better if there was a feature to specify that a specific transaction's results be unaffected by other concurrent transactions.

Comment: A specific transaction's results are *always* unaffected by other concurrent transactions. Your problem is concurrent statements in the *same* transaction. To make `SELECT` results unaffected by those, SQLite would need to create a temporary copy of the data even if it is not otherwise needed, or change its file format to store both old and new versions of the same data. Neither of these fits into the "Lite" design.

Comment: does separate connections per thread also solve the documented threads-overwrite-each-others-errmsgs issue?  But yeah if you are threading it's best to use transactions isolated from other threads,

Comment: Error information is stored in the connection object.